# how to access a element in right view of text box in xcuitest

Tags: xcuitest

I am new to XCUITESTING AND here is my code

```
   let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 50, height: 40))
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addEmail), for: .touchDown)
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "f_add_email"), for: .normal)
    btn.contentMode = .center
    btn.isAccessibilityElement = true
    btn.accessibilityIdentifier = "emailsbutton"

    txtField.isAccessibilityElement = true
    txtField.accessibilityIdentifier = "emailtextbox"
    txtField.rightViewMode = .always
    txtField.rightView = btn
```

i am able to access my textbox like XCUIApplication().textFields["emailtextbox"]

BUT if i use XCUIApplication().textFields["emailsbutton"] it throws error

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the button is under a textField. If so, you would need to access it with the following code:

```
XCUIApplication().textFields.buttons["emailsbutton"]
```

Comment: Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 'com.sample.workflow'
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type TextField
    ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Button
      ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"emailsbutton" IN identifiers'

it returns empty it doesnt works
XCUIApplication().textFields.buttons["emailsbutton"]

Comment: What does app.debugDescription return?try otherElements?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try this following things :

1 ) Always do `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` see that button Ids/label/title.

You can use buttons or otherElements to trigger tap on it.

```
XCUIApplication().buttons["emailsbutton"].tap()
```

OR

```
XCUIApplication().otherElements["emailsbutton"].tap()
```